# Generalizing an iterative logarithm integral.

Tags: integration, derivatives, logarithms, exponential-function, tetration

First, some notation:

$f^{\star0}(x)=x$

$f^{\star k}(x)=f\left(f^{\star k-1}(x)\right)$

So that for any integer $k$, $\log^{\star k}(x)=\underbrace{\log(\log(\dots(\log}_k(x))\dots))$.

I then came across the following integral:

$$\int\frac1{x\log(x)}dx=\log(\log(x))$$

Which I generalized into

$$\int\frac1{\prod_{n=0}^k\log^{\star n}(x)}dx=\log^{\star k+1}(x)$$

And was wondering if anyone had any idea as to how to extend this to non-integer $n$.  This would be of interest to generalizing the tetration, where 'half iterations' of the log would come in handy.

A similar integral involving the exponential function:

$$\int\prod_{n=1}^k\exp^{\star n}(x)dx=\exp^{\star n}(x)$$

I tried to generalize it by letting $\frac d{dx}\log^{\star k+1}(x)=\frac1{\prod_{n=0}^\infty\log^{\star k-n}(x)}$, but then convergence is an issue.  Same problem with the exponential case.

If someone manages a sneaky manipulation of sorts to generalize this, that'd be great.

Comment: Well we can generalize the infinite product with a limit , just like euler did with the gamma function. However in this case you have self-reference. Feels like defining gamma function with an infinite product of gamma functions.  If however you already have your tetration defined , the limit analogue works.

Comment: @mick That is ok, as I still want to generalize this.

Comment: I guess it should work : use results from Summability calculus (fractionnal sums exist so does frational products) use k real on side should give the definition , yet there is work and checks to be done.